# How to view the HTML page from the local path in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I have a package contains all the css, Js and HTML file in that package i have a index.html page which has an activity that loads in web browser, How to load it in mob app using react native.  My index.html file path is file:///Users/usarama/Documents/DownloadFlow/packets/test/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't render your web version on mobile as ionic framework provides.
Hope this link helps you 
https://medium.com/@alexmngn/from-reactjs-to-react-native-what-are-the-main-differences-between-both-d6e8e88ebf24

Answer (score 0):

Coming a bit late, but you actually can render your web version on mobile. You should look into  `react-native-webview` and `"react-native-static-server"`. The idea is that, you create a static server from within your RN application, and then pass the uri of that server to the WebView component. Take a look at [this guide.](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/08/28/static-http-server-react-native/)